# Suggestions on how to maintain both a web application project and a website from the same codebase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a relatively big "off-the-shelf" web application that is an ASP.NET website project at the moment. It was started when a website project was the only solution in the beta version of .net 2.0. We have quite a few customers using it.

Now we want to support MVC in the application. In order to support MVC properly, our solution must be run as a web application project. We want to make one of the project types the "master", and generate/modify the files needed for the other project type in a build script. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Anyone have done this? Or are we looking at this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's you are looking for is a solution. Then add as many and different project in it, they will build all together nicely.

Comment: No, I know what a solution is. We use a website project in Visual Studio. It compiles at runtime. We have no project files. No designer files etc. What I'm asking if anyone has experience with either auto generating the web application project specific files at build time, or if we convert our website project to a web application project, remove the web application project specific files at build time.